# how to show drop down on row as in Android device using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

Can you please tell me how to make this type of list view using jQuery +jQuery UI and jQuery Mobile? I am able to add rows in my list, but I need to add any icon on each row. On Click on each icon it should should this menu option. I am able to make row after click of button. It generate the rows after click of add button. I need to add pop screen on each icon of each row.

http://jsfiddle.net/FZQ8D/24/

```
function createTestCase(testCaseName,iscreatedFromScript,jsonObject) {
    var id;
    if (typeof ($("#testCaseContainer li:last").attr('id')) == 'undefined') {
        id = "tc_1";
        var index = id.indexOf("_");
        var count = id.substring(index + 1, id.length);
        count = parseInt(count);
        var conunter = count;
    } else {
        id = $("#testCaseContainer li:last").attr('id');
        var index = id.indexOf("_");
        var count = id.substring(index + 1, id.length);
        count = parseInt(count);
        var conunter = count;
        id = id.substring(0, index) + "_" + parseInt(count + 1);
    }
    var html = '<div class="testcaselist_row">' + '<ul>' + '<li id="' + id + '" class="clickTestCaseRow"><a href="#" style="color: #ffffff!important;">' + id + '</a></li>' + '</ul>' + '</div>';
    $('#testCaseContainer').append(html).enhanceWithin();
```

}

[image]

Comment: I started to edit your post but then realized there's just too much wrong with it. Fix it and I will gladly vote it up again, at this moment the sentences make no sense.

Comment: Ok I will Edited it..give me few seconds

Comment: @filoxo i don't have Idea of to make this type of list

Comment: @Morne please check my update .And up vote my Question

Comment: @user3665790 People will upvote high quality questions.  Low quality questions get downvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get you started, you will need to:

1. Create a menu handle element that will need to exist inline with your list item.
2. Create the menu itself. I did this inline but you could have done it somehow else.
3. Bind an event handler to display or hide the menu onclick. I used a custom `data` attribute to link the three-dot handle to the appropriate menu div.

I added to [your demo](http://jsfiddle.net/filoxo/FZQ8D/29/) to show this basic functionality. It still requires additional work (it still has bugs) but should get you started on extending its functionality to get you to your end goal.